# How to have different base_url for different environment instance in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

My index.html file of angular2 has following content:

I want that, when I build it in (npm run build)default mode (development mode), it should be

```
<base href="/">
```

But When I build it in production mode (npm run build --target=production), it should be

```
<base href="/new/">
```

I am expert in angular1, but new to angular2, but have tried to add a variable for base_url in index.ts file but that doesn't seems to be working.

I expect there muust be a quicker way to solve this, can anyone please help here.

Comment: if you're using webpack, you could using this plugin to inject to html when build https://www.npmjs.com/package/inject-html-webpack-plugin

Comment: we are not using this.. is that possible through angular-cli? or anyother way..

Comment: please see answer below, and @Pankaj Parkar is Angular expert.

Comment: @TiepPhan for Angular cli, your answer seems to be a best option for me ;)

Comment: @PankajParkar I'm a big fan of CLI ;-)

Comment: Ok..let me try CLI way..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because you're using Angular CLI, it does support very well

```
# Sets base tag href to /myUrl/ in your index.html
ng build --base-href /myUrl/
ng build -bh /myUrl/
```

you can update scripts in `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  //...
  "start": "ng serve -bh /anotheUrl/",
  "build": "ng build -bh /myUrl/",
  //..
},
```

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build

Comment: I'm glad to help!

Answer (score 2):

You could use [**`APP_BASE_HREF`**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/APP_BASE_HREF-let.html) provider to set its value

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [..],
  declarations: [..],
  providers: [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/new/'}]
})
class AppModule {}
```